# Libgdx app closes immediately after opening

Tags: java, libgdx, gradle

I have a libGdx app, and I am running it using android studio.

It closes immediately after starting it and I see no error report.
Could anyone help?

Starfield.java

```
public class Starfield extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private static final float STAR_DENSITY = 0.01f;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    Array<Vector2> stars;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Initialize a shapeRenderer
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        // Call initStars
        initStars(STAR_DENSITY);

    }

    public void initStars(float density) {
        // Figure out how many stars to draw. You'll need the screen dimensions,  which you can get using
        // Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and Gdx.graphics.getHeight().
        int screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        int screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        // Create a new array of Vector2's to hold the star positions
        stars = new Array<Vector2>((int) (screenHeight * screenWidth * density));

        // Use java.util.Random to fill the array of star positions
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < stars.size; i++) {

            int x = random.nextInt(screenWidth);
            int y = random.nextInt(screenHeight);

            stars.add(new Vector2(x, y));

        }

    }

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    initStars(STAR_DENSITY);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    // Make the night sky black
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Begin a shapeRenderer batch using ShapeType.Point
    shapeRenderer.begin();

    // Loop through the star positions and use shapeRenderer to draw points
    for (Vector2 vec: stars) {

        shapeRenderer.point(vec.x, vec.y, 0);

    }

    // End the shapeRenderer batch
    shapeRenderer.end();

 }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // Dispose of our ShapeRenderer
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is the gradle log

```
Run build   1s 241ms    
Run init scripts    33ms    
Configure settings  1ms 
Configure build 327ms   
Project :   326ms   
Resolve dependencies :classpath 200ms   
Resolve dependencies :android:classpath 0ms 
Calculate task graph    26ms    
Project :desktop    15ms    
Project :core   3ms 
Run tasks   824ms   
:core:compileJava   82ms    
Resolve dependencies :core:compileClasspath 5ms 
:core:processResources  3ms 
:core:classes   1ms 
:core:jar   16ms    
:desktop:compileJava    73ms    
Resolve dependencies :desktop:compileClasspath  14ms    
:desktop:processResources   2ms 
:desktop:classes    0ms 
:desktop:run    642ms   
Resolve dependencies :desktop:runtime   3ms
```

EDIT: I got an error, dumb me, I did not see the console.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalStateException:    autoShapeType must be true to use this method.
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.java:198)
at gamedev.starfield.Starfield.render(Starfield.java:87)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use a step-by-step debugger in Android Studio to spot where it crashes?

Comment: Just after the build! In the last line of the gradle build log.

Comment: if i try debugging, I get some error. `Error running Desktop: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:54999): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"`

Comment: Forget that, I put the stacktrace, I found an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `ShapeType` in the `begin` call on the `ShapeRenderer`.

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Point);
```